# Nginx always fire

Tags: nginx

I have two server

```
server {

    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root  /var/www/a;

    server_name a.example.com;

    index index.html index.php;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ .*\.(js|swf|css|jpg|gif|png|ico|eot|woff|svg|ttf|otf)$ {
        expires 30d;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass php7:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

and

```
server {

    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root  /var/www/b;

    server_name b.example.com;

    index index.html index.php;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ .*\.(js|swf|css|jpg|gif|png|ico|eot|woff|svg|ttf|otf)$ {
        expires 30d;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass php7:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

in `/var/www/a` there are `index.php`:

```
i am a
```

in `/var/www/b` there are `index.php`:

```
i am b
```

I visit `a.example.com`, result `i am a`, that is good.

I visit `b.example.com`, result `i am b`, that is good.

***But i visit `asdf.example.com`, it result `i am a`.***

***what is more, i visit `werwe.asdf.example.com`, it result `i am a`.***

it seem that whatever i visit with `*.example.com` it always return `i am a`

i want to know why.

Thanks.

---

It is my `nginx.conf`

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very normal . You can see the describe in Nginx Document here : http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html

```
When searching for a virtual server by name, if name matches more than one of the specified variants, e.g. both wildcard name and regular expression match, the first matching variant will be chosen, in the following order of precedence:

1.exact name
2.longest wildcard name starting with an asterisk, e.g. “*.example.org”
3.longest wildcard name ending with an asterisk, e.g. “mail.*”
4.first matching regular expression (in order of appearance in a configuration file)
```

So, in your situation, domain your domain doesn't match any server name, nginx use the first ever seen server block.

To fix this, you should create a server block name `defaultvhost`  with   `server_name  _;`, and all unknown  domain with be served in this server block ( virtual host) .

Hope it works .

Comment: but ```a``` and ```b``` server use exact name there are no asterisk and  regular expression,why it still always direct to ```a```?

Comment: That's right.  Nginx try to find best matched domain. if no domain found, it use the first server block ever. I've edit my posts for correct answer.

Comment: As I can see, you make  requests to a.example.com and b.example.com which are exactly domain names.  But when you request to asdf.example.com or werwe.asdf.example.com, no server block with these domains are declared. Nginx use the first ever server block.

Comment: Thank you,i have accepted your answer and i have found the reason in [http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html)

Comment: cool. good for you.

Answer (score 0):

I have find the answer in nginx docs http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html

> nginx first decides which server should process the request. Let’s
>   start with a simple configuration where all three virtual servers
>   listen on port *:80:
>
> ```
> server {
>     listen      80;
>     server_name example.org www.example.org;
>     ...
> }
>
> server {
>     listen      80;
>     server_name example.net www.example.net;
>     ...
> }
>
> server {
>     listen      80;
>     server_name example.com www.example.com;
>     ...
> }
> ```
>
> In this configuration nginx tests only the request’s header field
>   “Host” to determine which server the request should be routed to. If
>   its value does not match any server name, or the request does not
>   contain this header field at all, then nginx will route the request to
>   the default server for this port. In the configuration above, the
>   default server is the first one — which is nginx’s standard default
>   behaviour. It can also be set explicitly which server should be
>   default, with the default_server parameter in the listen directive:
>
> ```
> server {
>     listen      80 default_server;
>     server_name example.net www.example.net;
>     ...
> }
> ```

so if there are no `server_name` matched and no `default_server` specified, the first server will be use as `default_server` .

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 0):

Add this as an enabled site

```
# This just prevents Nginx picking a random default server if it doesn't know which
# server block to send a request to
server {
  listen      80 default_server;
  server_name _;
  access_log off; log_not_found off;
  return 444;
}
```